# How to have longer key bindings for stty

Tags: terminal, key-mapping

If I want to have more than 2 key sequence for binding to the suspend signal, how would I do that? To clarify, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> is for suspending. But if I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> and a <kbd>k</kbd> with the previous 2 keys depressed to perform the same function, how would I do that?

I have tried various combos w success. For eg:

```
stty susp \^ZV
```

I use a tty terminal so emulators like xterm will not help in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stty susp` tells the terminal driver what *character* (actually what *byte*), when received unescaped from the terminal (via the wire if a real terminal, or written to the master side of a pseudo-terminal in case of a terminal emulator or `sshd`...), when `ISIG` is on, causes a SIGTSTP to be sent to the foreground job.

There's no key or keyboard involved here. It's the `^Z` character by default (0x1a). `xterm` and other terminal emulators generally send that character when you press <kbd>Z</kbd> while holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

If you want to make it harder to suspend a process, you could configure your terminal emulator so that it doesn't send `^Z` upon <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, but upon some other key combination. With `xterm`:

```
xterm -xrm 'XTerm.VT100.translations: #override \
  Ctrl Shift <KeyPress> X: string(0x1a)\nCtrl <KeyPress> Z:'
```

Sends the `^Z` character upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+X</kbd>, not upon <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>. With xterm, I don't think you can specify arbitrary key combinations, you can only use modifier keys like Ctrl or Shift.

Of course, you could also define a different byte for `stty susp` and have `xterm` send it on a different key combination.

Note that you probably don't want to make it a byte over 0x7f as those would appear in different UTF-8 characters.

Comment: If I do `stty susp \^K `, then I would have changed it to **Ctrl K**. Is there a wayI can do it using stty instead of xterm?

Comment: @sunyata, I'm not sure I understand your question, if you do `stty susp \^K`, same as `stty susp $'\xb'`, you're telling the terminal driver to suspend upon the 0xb character. That character is usually sent by `xterm` upon pressing Ctrl+K, but you can configure `xterm` to send it upon a different event.

Comment: I use a tty so xterm will not help.

Comment: @sunyata, what do you mean by _tty_? a Tele-typewriter? A Linux virtual console? In the latter case, the equivalent would be to modify the kernel key map (look at `man 5 keymap`).

Comment: By tty, I refer to a linux local terminal. I have since moved project so I no longer have the same environment to try things out. Thanks for your response.